# What approach should I use for JavaFX Canvas multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2

I am writing a JavaFX application that receives data points on a socket and visualizes them in real time. The problem is that the JavaFX rendering is too slow. I have a Swing implementation that runs fast enough but I need to use JavaFX instead.

The constraints that I am working within are:

1. The control for the visualization must only be updated by the JavaFX application thread (I believe this is required for all JavaFX and Swing applications).
2. The visualization should be updated smoothly from the perspective of the human eye. Around 10 updates per second would be sufficient. Once every second would not be sufficient.
3. The incoming data rate is high enough (about 50 events per second which is not that high in other contexts) and the per event processing is expensive enough that the incoming data must be received and processed in a thread other than the JavaFX application thread so that the GUI doesn't block (I believe this is a somewhat common requirement for many GUI applications).

My approach so far has been to use a Canvas JavaFX node as the visualization control and for the reception thread to schedule updates to the Canvas to run later in the JavaFX application thread, like this.

```
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        ....do processing... 
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphics.setFill(...);
                graphics.fillRect(...);
                }});
    }
```

I have thought of a couple of approaches that might speed this up:

1. Use a WritableImage instead of a Canvas for the visualization. The downside is that WritableImage/PixelWriter doesn't seem to have many drawing methods, for example it doesn't even have fillRect. I think I would have to implement my own versions and my versions would probably be slower.
2. Have a Canvas object owned by the thread that processes incoming data. Copy from that canvas to the canvas that is a node in the scene graph in the JavaFX application thread. The copy would probably be done with code along these lines `sceneCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D().drawImage(processingCanvas.snapshot(SnapshotParameters(), null) 0, 0);`. The downside of this is that I think it isn't thread safe and it seems that the snapshot call is relatively expensive.
3. Render to an AWT BufferedImage in the thread that processes incoming data and then copy from the BufferedImage to the Canvas using SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(). The downside of this is that the threading semantics seem unclear and it seems a little silly to use AWT.

Would you be able to suggest some potential approaches?

Thank you!

Comment: You could build up an FX canvas in your processing thread and then hand it over to the FX application thread (via Platform.runLater) to exchange the "old" canvas in the scene graph.

Comment: Have you already measured how long your canvas drawing method runs?

Comment: The drawing method is relatively fast, usually less than a millisecond. I figured out that the biggest problem was that the code was using Platform.runLater(). Increasing the work done in each Platform.runLater() call significantly improved the throughput of the application. I'm not sure if the problem was the overhead of Platform.runLater() or if the problem was that JavaFX was interleaving the Platform.runLater() calls with pulse calls resulting in more repaints. I'm still curious what people think is a good architectural approach for an app like this. Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you've got continuously more data events than your FX application thread could process. This fills up the event queue and keeps the FX application thread busy all the time.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the canvas (`clearRect(0, 0, w, h)`) between calls?  See, [RT-32242 Canvas should clear its buffered commands on certain clearRect, fillRect calls](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32242).  Another option is to use a pull method rather than a push method (e.g. have an AnimationTimer which polls an event queue of processed data and re-renders the image when the data changes).  It's a bit hard to provide a general recommendation without writing quite a long and detailed answer.

Comment: The clearRect() idea is a good one! I don't think it will help in this case since the visualization is additive. The pull method looks great. I think that is the same as what isnot2bad suggested.

Comment: Just to say +1 because this is a much better question than your last one that I commented on.  I think you deleted it, but you can also just edit the original if you want.

Comment: @brian sorry, what question do you mean?

Comment: @JohnCashew, There was an almost identical question around last week. It doesn't matter, this is still a good question.

Comment: @brain, that's funny! well, it wasn't me who asked that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume, the main problem is that your code pushes too many drawing-tasks into the queue of your FX Application thread. Usually, it is sufficient to have 60 drawing operations per second, which is equal to the refresh rate of your monitor. If you get more "incoming data" events than that, you'll draw more often than necessary, wasting CPU. So you must decouple data processing from painting.

One solution is to use an `AnimationTimer`. Its `handle` method will be called in every animation frame, so usually 60 times per second. The animation timer handles redrawing in case new data has been processed.

```
// generic task that redraws the canvas when new data arrives
// (but not more often than 60 times per second).
public abstract class CanvasRedrawTask<T> extends AnimationTimer {
    private final AtomicReference<T> data = new AtomicReference<T>(null);
    private final Canvas canvas;

    public CanvasRedrawTask(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void requestRedraw(T dataToDraw) {
        data.set(dataToDraw);
        start(); // in case, not already started
    }

    public void handle(long now) {
        // check if new data is available
        T dataToDraw = data.getAndSet(null);
        if (dataToDraw != null) {
            redraw(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(), dataToDraw);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void redraw(GraphicsContext context, T data);
}

// somewhere else in your concrete canvas implementation
private final RedrawTask<MyData> task = new RedrawTask<MyData>(this) {
    void redraw(GraphicsContext context, MyData data) {
        // TODO: redraw canvas using context and data
    }
}

// may be called by a different thread
public void onDataReceived(...) {
    // process data / prepare for redraw task
    // ...

    // handover data to redraw task
    task.requestRedraw(dataToDraw);
}
```

Comment: This will be great approach! Thank you for the suggestion